# ERROR mysql #1064

Tags: mysql

I have an error in my syntax SQL when I upload my database on a server the error is this one:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 14

this is the PHP

```
CREATE TABLE `nxuri_assets` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
);
```

Thanks

Comment: no, that's not php. that's just sql. and you're missing an actual comment on the parent_id line. a comment cannot be blank.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a comment for this table, but you have not provided the comment text.

To solve syntax errors, I recommend you familiarize yourself with reading documentation. It's much more efficient than posting to Stack Overflow every time you have a simple question.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Default '0' should be just DEFAULT 0 (no quotes).  Also, remove the COMMENT or put a space between the comment and 0.

Try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE nxuri_assets (id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key', parent_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nxuri_assets` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);
```